# GroupDAV client app for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, applications

I am considering setting up a Citadel groupware server. It natively supports syncing via the GroupDAV protocol.

Is there an app for the iPhone that lets it sync its calendars, contacts, and tasks with a GroupDAV server?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, GroupDAV is a superset of, or at least [closely related](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GroupDAV) to, WebDAV/CalDAV, for which the iPhone has built in support.

You could try fiddling with your iPhone's calendar app. Adding a CalDAV account may work.